# in Rails 3, how is the id passed in an update statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm having problems not having a params[:id] value in an update action.

I get "Couldn't find Menu without an ID" - it does have a id="edit_menu_1" in the form element.

If I run a scaffold for a similar item, this seems like it would be what is being picked up by the update statement (ie no id value in the POST statement). Is this the correct value that I should be looking for / debugging? Is there a standard Rails debug technique, where I can for the id value in (say like hidden form field of the correct id)?

thx

Edit#1
From development.log
Scaffolded (id value exists):

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HfMoJHPC7oFFYDcmeHh4tVzlRtpreQTYT75L7TDZ3Qs=", "menu"=>{"content"=>"here is my menu - more things for you"}, "commit"=>"Update Menu", "id"=>"1"}
```

My App (no id value)

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xr82q8+YSj7z1WorVedqUKzEYroycDslMgRqgZf5crQ=", "menu"=>{"name"=>"Bar Menu - some thigs"}, "commit"=>"Update Menu"}
```

My form code is:

```
<%= form_for(@menu ,  :url =>  menus_save2_path)  do |f| %>
   <div><%=f.text_field :name %></div>
```

1. How would I force in the id value?
2. Makes sense but if I look at the scaffolded code, there's not a hidden parameter for the id value. Is this getting automagically done?

Comment: Have you overridden the usual integer `id` field to contain strings instead? What is `id="edit_menu_1"` - looks like it is the id of a html element, not a record id in a database table?

Comment: right, is the id of the `form` element for the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `params` are always shown in `log/development.log` so you should see what parameters you are present when the request is serviced. Generally the `:id` parameter is provided in the URL, not the HTML form, and is produced by the routing system. Your parameter may be absent because you forgot to include it in the target URL of your `form_tag` or `form_for` call.

Comment: added development log and form_for - I think I'm doing this correctly in terms of passing in model. thx

Comment: What's the routing for `menus_save2_path` from `rake routes`? It might require an argument, like `menus_save2_path(@menu)`

Comment: yeah, i think you're right - I just started reworking this in rails default REST approach and is working... The explanations on this are, to be honest, way too long-winded.